# Dataframe column name compare

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Dataframe Country has below columns

```
Index(['hasData', 'key', 'level', 'name', 'id', 'oecd-code', 'regionid'], dtype='object')
```

I want to perform some actions if Country.columns contains 'oecd-code' column

My Code:

```
if Country.columns.isin(['oecd-code']):
      #Some actions
```

Country.columns.isin(['oecd-code']) gives

```
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

How to filter from array if it has True value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `.isin`, you can do:

```
select_cols = ['oecd-code']
col_mask = Country.columns.isin(select_cols)
Country[Country.columns[col_mask]]
```

or

```
Country.loc[:, col_mask]
```

However, you can simply do the following.

```
Country[select_cols]
```

EDIT: If you only want to check whether `'oecd-code'` is a column of `Country`, just check `'oecd-code' in Country.columns`, or in fact `'oecd-code' in Country`, or, if you already have your boolean array, use `.any()` to check if any of the values are `True`.

Comment: i just want to check column 'oecd-code' exist in Country.columns or not?